# Manage GPOs in one console in two forests without trust in place

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain

I have two forests that have no trust between them - and can't configure it because of security reasons. I need to manage both forests from dedicated PC with one console that can manage GPOs in both forests at once = in one console window. I have credentials for both forests, just can't connect them. I am struggling to find any reference how to do this without trust or someone who already sucesfully did this?

Comment: What is the networking configuration between the two forests?

Comment: One console window - not going to work. `I am struggling to find any reference how to do this`. Not surprising because no-one does it.